# "Must supply cloud_name" error when using Cloudinary

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cloudinary

I am using Cloudinary to host some images which I need to display in a Next.js application. I'm testing this locally with `npm run dev`.

```
import Link from '/src/Link';

import { Cloudinary } from '@cloudinary/url-gen';
import { scale } from "@cloudinary/url-gen/actions/resize";

const cld = new Cloudinary({
    cloud: {
        cloudName: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    },
    url: {
        secure: true // force https
    }
});

export default function QImage({ info }) {
    const thumb = cld.image(info.public_id).resize(scale().width(200));
    const img = cld.image(info.public_id).resize(scale().width(1600));
    const size = `${info.width}-${info.height}`

    return (
        <Link href={img.toURL()} color="secondary" key={info.asset_id} data-lg-size={size}>
            <img src={thumb.toURL()} />
        </Link>
    )
}
```

Intermittently, rendering of the page will fail with this error:

```
error - Error: Must supply cloud_name
    at getProperError (/proj/node_modules/next/dist/lib/is-error.js:41:12)
    at DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (/proj/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1343:53)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (/proj/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:630:25)
    at async Object.fn (/proj/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:1144:21)
    at async Router.execute (/proj/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:315:32)
    at async DevServer.runImpl (/proj/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:604:29)
    at async DevServer.run (/proj/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:922:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/proj/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:533:20) {
  digest: undefined
}
```

This stack is not helpful. I have confirmed that the correct `cloudName` is in the environment and being passed to the config. What else could cause this?

**UPDATE:** When this happens, visiting the index page of the site (with only Cloudinary Admin API calls) seems to fix it. If I then return to the page which loads the component excerpted here, the error goes away.

Could it be to do with some conflict between the two Cloudinary configuration setups? My other page is using [`resources` calls](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#get_resources_examples) from the `v2` API [like this](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration#setting_configuration_parameters_globally):

```js
import { v2 as cloudinary } from 'cloudinary'

cloudinary.config({ 
  cloud_name: 'sample', 
  api_key: '874837483274837', 
  api_secret: 'a676b67565c6767a6767d6767f676fe1',
  secure: true
});
```

Comment: The Cloudinary package have to be loaded as `import cloudinary from "cloudinary";` and it can be initialized as `cloudinary.v2.config({...});` - you may refer to this [documentation for more information](https://dev.to/hackmamba/image-and-video-upload-to-cloudinary-using-nextjs-server-side-multer-and-xata-database-3l9f). Additionally, you could check through the console log if you are able to load the .env variables data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am using the import suggested by Cloudinary, which I've added to the second excerpt now. The `v2` issue DID trip me up before, but that's not the problem here. To be clear, the Admin API calls are succeeding, it's just loading the subordinate pages which is failing until I re-visit the main page. I'm using SSG to build the routes from the index page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't initializing the library in every situation. Instead of having to remember to call `cloudinary.config()` before each use, sometimes multiple times per file, I now have a separate file:

*src/cloudinary.js*

```js
import cloudinaryLib from 'cloudinary'

const cloudinary = cloudinaryLib.v2

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET,
  secure: true,
})

export default cloudinary
```

And then importing is both easy and always fully configured:

```js
import cloudinary from '/src/cloudinary'

// ...

cloudinary.url(/* etc */)
```